# I Think I'm Due For A New HD (reallocated sectors)

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, high-definition, sectors

My computer has been running crazy slow for quite awhile..I've done all the normal fixes I could dig up and even did a complete factory reset of the computer

Things were running better and now they are slow again.

I ran crystaldiskinfo and it's telling me my hard drive health is bad. It shows down below that it has 1 reallocated sector which is one too many...I know

but I've seen a bunch of people with way more.

Here's the kicker:

When I highlight the part where it describes hd health as bad it says reallocated sector count: 100000

I've never seen anyone's go over 9000! And don't know if mine really did because down below it says 1.

Anyone want to help me make sense of these numbers and let me know if I'd be well served buying a fresh (probably SSD) HD?

[image: reallocated sectors]

Comment: What’s even worse is that you have additional “pending sectors” indicating the drive is continuing to degrade. This drive has been power cycled 2028 times over only 4068 hours of use??? Are you sure you don’t have a bad power cable on the drive? That could be what caused it to fail prematurely... or it’s just a seagate.

Comment: One reallocated sector isn't too many.  One sector that gets reallocated **in use** is too many.  The difference is ones locked out due to a flaw at the time of manufacture don't matter, ones that fail in use do.

Comment: @Appleoddity the power cycles can refer to the amount of times it powered on and off right? When I was reinstalling windows I encountered a boot loop so it cycled itself through a whole bunch. that may have caused that. Oh and the HD is a Toshiba apparently...it's the one that came with my Acer computer.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I ordered myself an SSD so hopefully that'll work much better for me. I figure the 1 reallocated drive is bad enough with all the other details around it. I still don't fully understand where that 10,000 comes from. I just want my computer to run faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can never remember how the current/worst/threshold values are normalized. What you should pay attention to in this case is the raw value.

Your raw value is a hexadecimal value of 2710, which is 10,000 in decimal. So yes, you're playing with a ticking time bomb.

If you're not already familiar with it, a reallocate sector is when a specific sector of the hard drive platter can no longer be trusted to store data. The hard drive will move the data from the bad sectors to known good sectors. The bad sectors will then be marked and not used again.

You should definitely replace the hard drive as soon as possible, and backup any data that you feel is important. If you'd like you could use another tool like HDDScanner or GSmartControl to verify and see the raw values that they display for reallocated sectors.

Since you're using a 5400 RPM drive, you'll see a fantastic increase in performance if you end up choosing to get an SSD.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I just ordered an SSD drive. Less total space but I have a couple TB external drives so I should be fine. Is there anything I can do to prevent drives from having these reallocated sectors in the future?

Comment: I wonder if it could be a misinterpretation though (like the vendor abused the the field for something else). An exact number like 10000 sounds suspicious to me.

Comment: I'm not too sure honestly.  I have a hard time making sense of it...if there's a one down below and that's the current reallocated sectors yet there are 10000 about to fail. Not sure... regardless I care less about lost data because everything is already backed up and more about getting my computer to run reasonably once again